# Flex : How to validate for spaces in text field?

Tags: apache-flex, validation, flex4

I have a password field. Which checks if it has a min of 8 characters and property set to required. However I do not want the user to enter any spaces in the text field . How can i do this ?

This is my validation codes in my Declarations tags :

```
    <mx:StringValidator id="userPasswordValidator"                          
                        property="text"                                                     
                        required="true"                         
                        minLength="8"                           
                        tooShortError="password must at least be 8 characters"
                        source="{userPassword_field}"/>
```

My text field in my MXML :

```
<s:TextInput id="userPassword_field" x="73" y="48" width="109" height="21" displayAsPassword="true"/>
```

pls can someone tell me how I can validate for spaces in text fields ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply stop a user to enter spaces in text input. just allow user to add allowed character in text input.

```
<s:TextInput id="userPassword_field" x="73" y="48" width="109" height="21" displayAsPassword="true" restrict="A-Z\a-z\0-9"/>
```

use 'restrict="A-Z\a-z\0-9"' to restrict user.

Comment: If I want to allow characters like - , * , \  but just don't allow spaces. what will be the regular expressions ?  cause currently it only allows alphabets and and numbers.

Comment: u can get help from 
(http://ryanswanson.com/regexp/)

This a great tool for regular expression..

just add required chars in restrict field. and also add maxChar property to textInput.

restrict="A-Z\a-z\0-9*-"

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the contents of the field against the contents with the spaces replaced.  If they are not the same then tell user.

e.g

```
<Input type="password" onchange="return noSpaces(this)" />
function noSpaces(myInputElem)
{
  var returnVal=true;
  if(myInputElem.value!=myInputElem.value.replace(" ",""))
  {
    alert("Spaces not allowed");
    returnVal=false;
  }
  return returnVal;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but thats the idea.

Answer (score 0):

setting restrict="^ " will allow everything except space.